# How can I view an XLXS file attachment to a gmail message?

Tags: storage

I received an email message with an XLXS file attached.  I can see the attachment icon in the email message in the gmail app and it appears that I can download the file but it is not viewable in Downloads the way attachments that I download from Yahoo mail are.  It seems to get saved to some file storage area labeled as Miscellaneous files, but I can't view the file.  How do I view it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you don't have an app that can view excel spreadsheet (.xlsx). Solution: Download an app that can view them, such as [Google Sheets](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs.editors.sheets), then try to open the file again